# Auto login to CLI in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, login

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a RPi 3. I've disabled the GUI and want to operate in CLI only but would like to have it auto login at startup. I've read:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm#51087

although I'm not sure it applies to my case and didn't work anyway (the `lightdm.conf` file I found was in `/etc/init/`

And this

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin

but there is no `tty1.conf` file that I can find to edit.

Is there a method specific to my situation that I can't find?

Comment: Ubuntu and Raspbian are both built on the same base, Debian. The only big differences are in the GUI. Since you're not using the GUI are you sure you don't want to just use Raspbian which has a better package respository and more support for things like this?

Comment: I'm aiming to use Swift 3 and the install instructions indicate to use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What about this? http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/swift-3-0-on-raspberry-pi-2-and-3/

Comment: Thanks, yes I've read that. It's what I used to install Swift, and it uses Xenial which is, I believe, 16.04. I'd like to use it headless so would like an auto-login.

Comment: Ok I know your question was about Xenial but I think it can be done on Raspbian easily without even building it: https://medium.com/a-swift-misadventure/installing-swift-3-0-preview-on-a-raspberry-pi-2-3-with-raspbian-3e857fa995d9

Comment: ....and yes sorry that other link was with Xenial, I missed that.